# Trouble with gmp_xor on 32 bit

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, gmp

On a 64-bit machine

```
(1 ^ 2489596804)
```

gives `-1805370491` in response.  However, when I do this on a 32-bit PHP machine, I get `2489596805` in response.

So, I tried to get it working on the 32-bit machine using `gmp_strval(gmp_xor(1,2489596804))`, but it also yields `2489596805`.  So what's up, and how can I get the right response?

Update: I just noticed that the 64-bit result is what you get from subtracting the 32-bit max from it (`4294967295`).

Comment: you mean 64 bit machine?

Comment: Bitwise operations are only well-defined for unsigned integers. For signed integers the result is implementation-defined.

Comment: Fair enough, but what can I do to get that result?

Comment: @Kerrek: Bitwise operations are well defined for signed integers *in PHP*.

Comment: Oh, whoops, PHP -- I saw "GMP" and thought of C! My bad. What's the behaviour for signed integers then? Or can you explicitly make an integer unsigned in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same result, simply interpreted differently:

```
0x94643B85 =  2489596805 (unsigned 32-bit integer)
0x94643B85 = -1805370491 (signed 32-bit integer)
```

The reason you see a negative value on your 64-bit machine is that you're interpreting that result as a signed 32-bit integer.

If you really want to convert between the two interpretations, I think you'll have to do this yourself. A simple way to do that would be something like this:

```
<?php
function toSigned($value) {
  if ($value <= 2147483647)
    return $value;
  return $value - 4294967295 + 1;
}

function toUnsigned($value) {
  if ($value >= 0)
    return $value;
  return $value + 4294967295 - 1;
}
```